# Play Framework using View Tags

Tags: scala, playframework

This is my day 1 with play framework and I am using view templates

Application.scala

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
class Application extends Controller {

  val productMap = Map(1 -> "Keyboard", 2 -> "Mouse", 3 -> "Monitor")

  def listProducts() = Action {
    Ok(views.html.products(productMap.values.toSeq))
  }
}
```

routes

```
GET     /listProducts      controllers.Application.listProducts
```

View

```
@(products: Seq[String])
@import tags._
@productsIterator(products)
```

View Tag

```
@(products: Seq[String])
<ul>
    @for(product <- products) {
        <li>@product</li>
    }
</ul>
```

The error I am getting is

```
 @6mgadekbj - Internal server error, for (GET) [/listProducts] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[**too many arguments for method apply**: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class productsIterator]
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks really good to me. Maybe it's some old compilation from older code? `./activator clean`.

Comment: you are right. renaming did not solve the issue. I renamed the file back to productsIterator and it still works. so I guess your suggestion of stopping the activator and then cleaning did resolve the issue.

Comment: Great, just to reassure you - I've never had the need to do that, so this is just an unfortunate one off I'm sure. It recompiles on the fly (next time the relevant code is run, to be exact).